# Visual Studio 2015 - Xamarin Installation failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I downloaded Xamarin from the website and the installation fails after downloading the android SDK manager, I retried a few times, still no positive results. Should I uninstall Xamarin, if so, how? What should I do, I want to code a IOS and Android application.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio 2017, you can add Xamarin as a package on there. I also tried installing Xamarin Studio from the website and the Android SDK fails to download after a while, I'm not sure what the issue is with that. It does download like 7GB of files that you will need to manually delete if you tried installing Xamarin Studio.

Comment: This is a fairly low quality question. Please provide more info on what kind(s) of error message(s) did you get, have you tried uninstalling, have you done any searching in your search engines? Asking these types of questions on `SO` should be a last resort with really clear "steps of things you've already tried" or your questions will be deleted.